# Is it possible to make "keydown" events trigger existing click events in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a calculator that is currently only usable by clicking the numbers. I'd like to make it work with the keyboard as well by having, for example, the "1" key trigger my existing click event.

Is this something that is possible? My research has only showed keypresses triggering their own functions but it seemed like bad practice to copy and paste the existing logic into new functions just to make key presses work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <p id = "display">0</p>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" id="btn1"> 1 </button>
    <button type="button" id="btn2"> 2 </button>
    <button type="button" id="btn3"> 3 </button>
    <button type="button" id="btn4"> 4 </button>
    <button type="button" id="btn5"> 5 </button>
    <button type="button" id="btn6"> 6 </button>
    <button type="button" id="btn7"> 7 </button>
    <button type="button" id="btn8"> 8 </button>
    <button type="button" id="btn9"> 9 </button>
    <button type="button" id="btn0"> 0 </button>
    <button type="button" id="btnDot"> . </button>

    <button type="button" id="btnPls"> + </button>
    <button type="button" id="btnSub"> - </button>
    <button type="button" id="btnMult"> x </button>
    <button type="button" id="btnDiv"> / </button>
    <button type="button" id="btnEq"> = </button>
    <button type="button" id="btnBkSp"> Backspace</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnClear"> clear </button>

  </div>



  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function addNumbers(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2
}

function subtractNumbers(num1, num2) {
    return num1 - num2
}

function multiplyNumbers(num1, num2) {
    return num1 * num2
}

function divideNumbers(num1, num2) {
    return num1 / num2
}

function operate(operator, num1, num2) {
    //set this up so the button sets the operator
    if (operator == '+') {
        return addNumbers(num1, num2);
    }

    else if (operator == '-') {
        return subtractNumbers(num1, num2);
    }

    else if (operator == '*') {
        return multiplyNumbers(num1, num2);
    }

    else if (operator == '/') {
        return divideNumbers(num1, num2);
    }
}
//const button1 = document.querySelector("#btn1");
//I could've done this the whole time but lets keep up the consistency of my laziness
let displayBox = document.getElementById("display").textContent;

//Number variables
let firstNumber = 0;
let secondNumber = 0;
let userInput = 0;

//Symbol variable
let operatorText = '';

//Boolean variables
let plusSelected = false;
let subSelected = false;
let multSelected = false;
let divSelected = false;
let firstNumberStored = false;

//Have to make textContent equal a variable
/*function displayInput() {
    document.getElementById("display").textContent = 1;
    console.log(this);
}*/

//const display = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
//create another function that stores the input of the click
    // run THAT function on click. Use output of that function to
    // figure out which number to display and so on

//Button One
btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (userInput == 0) {
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = "" + 1;
        console.log(userInput);     
    }
    else {
        userInput = userInput.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        //document.getElementById("display").textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        console.log(userInput);  
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput + 1;
           
    }

});

//Button Two
btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (userInput == 0) {
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = "" + 2;
        console.log(userInput);     
    }
    else {
        userInput = userInput.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        //document.getElementById("display").textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        console.log(userInput);  
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput + 2;
           
    }
});

//Button Three
btn3.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (userInput == 0) {
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = "" + 3;
        console.log(userInput);     
    }
    else {
        userInput = userInput.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        //document.getElementById("display").textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        console.log(userInput);  
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput + 3;
           
    }
});

//Button Four
btn4.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (userInput == 0) {
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = "" + 4;
        console.log(userInput);     
    }
    else {
        userInput = userInput.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        //document.getElementById("display").textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        console.log(userInput);  
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput + 4;
           
    }
});

//Button Five
btn5.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (userInput == 0) {
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = "" + 5;
        console.log(userInput);     
    }
    else {
        userInput = userInput.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        //document.getElementById("display").textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        console.log(userInput);  
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput + 5;
           
    }
});

//Button Six
btn6.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (userInput == 0) {
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = "" + 6;
        console.log(userInput);     
    }
    else {
        userInput = userInput.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        //document.getElementById("display").textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        console.log(userInput);  
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput + 6;
           
    }
});

//Button Seven
btn7.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (userInput == 0) {
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = "" + 7;
        console.log(userInput);     
    }
    else {
        userInput = userInput.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        //document.getElementById("display").textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        console.log(userInput);  
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput + 7;
           
    }
});

//Button Eight
btn8.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (userInput == 0) {
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = "" + 8;
        console.log(userInput);     
    }
    else {
        userInput = userInput.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        //document.getElementById("display").textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        console.log(userInput);  
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput + 8;
           
    }
});

//Button Nine
btn9.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (userInput == 0) {
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = "" + 9;
        console.log(userInput);     
    }
    else {
        userInput = userInput.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        //document.getElementById("display").textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        console.log(userInput);  
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput + 9;
           
    }
});

//Button Zero
btn0.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (userInput == 0) {
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = "" + 0;
        console.log(userInput);     
    }
    else {
        userInput = userInput.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        //document.getElementById("display").textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        console.log(userInput);  
        userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput + 0;
           
    }
});

//Button decimal point
btnDot.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (document.getElementById("display").textContent.includes(".")) {
        alert("Numbers can only contain one decimal point, chief.")
    }
    else {
        if (userInput == 0) {
            userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = ".";
            console.log(userInput);     
        }
        else {
            userInput = userInput.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
            //document.getElementById("display").textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
            console.log(userInput);  
            userInput = document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput + ".";
           
        }
    }
});

//OperatorButtons
//Addition Button
btnPls.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (plusSelected == true) {
        //this does nothing. make it grey out button in css or something
    }
    else {
    firstNumberStored = true;
    plusSelected = true;
    firstNumber = document.getElementById("display").textContent;
    userInput = 0;
    console.log(firstNumber);
    operatorText = document.getElementById("display").textContent = "+";
    }
});

//Subtraction Button
btnSub.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (subSelected == true) {
        //grey it out doooooood
    }
    else {
    firstNumberStored = true;
    subSelected = true;
    firstNumber = document.getElementById("display").textContent;
    userInput = 0;
    console.log(firstNumber);
    operatorText = document.getElementById("display").textContent = " - ";
    }
});

//Multiplication Button
btnMult.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (multSelected == true) {
        //grey
    }
    else {
    firstNumberStored = true;
    multSelected = true;
    firstNumber = document.getElementById("display").textContent;
    userInput = 0;
    console.log(firstNumber);
    operatorText = document.getElementById("display").textContent ="x";
    }
});

//Division Button
btnDiv.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (divSelected == true) {
        //yuh
    }
    else {
    firstNumberStored = true;
    divSelected = true;
    firstNumber = document.getElementById("display").textContent;
    userInput = 0;
    console.log(firstNumber);
    operatorText = document.getElementById("display").textContent = "/";
    }
});

//Equals Button
btnEq.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (!firstNumberStored || !userInput) {
        //grey it out brudda
        console.log("Nothing happened, ya goof");
    }
    else {
    if (plusSelected == true) {
        firstNumber = parseFloat(firstNumber);
        userInput = parseFloat(userInput);
        firstNumber = addNumbers(firstNumber,userInput);
        firstNumber = Math.round((firstNumber + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
        }
        else if (subSelected == true) {
            firstNumber = parseFloat(firstNumber);
            userInput = parseFloat(userInput);
            firstNumber = subtractNumbers(firstNumber,userInput);
            firstNumber = Math.round((firstNumber + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
        }
        else if (multSelected == true) {
            firstNumber = parseFloat(firstNumber);
            userInput = parseFloat(userInput);
            firstNumber = multiplyNumbers(firstNumber,userInput);
            firstNumber = Math.round((firstNumber + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
        }
        else if (divSelected == true) {
            firstNumber = parseFloat(firstNumber);
            userInput = parseFloat(userInput);
            if (userInput == 0) {
                firstNumber = "We all make mistakes in the heat of passion, Jimbo.";
            }
            else {
                firstNumber = divideNumbers(firstNumber,userInput);
                firstNumber = Math.round((firstNumber + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
            }
            
        }


    document.getElementById("display").textContent = firstNumber;

    userInput = 0;
    plusSelected = false;
    subSelected = false;
    multSelected = false;
    divSelected = false;
    operatorText = '';
    }
});

//Backspace Button
btnBkSp.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (operatorText && firstNumberStored && userInput){
        userInput = userInput.slice(0, -1);
        document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput;
        if (!userInput){
            operatorText = document.getElementById("display").textContent = operatorText;
            
        }
        /*
        else {
        document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput;
        console.log("FUDGE");
        }*/
    
        
    
    }
    else if (!userInput && operatorText){
        operatorText = '';
        plusSelected = false;
        subSelected = false;
        multSelected = false;
        divSelected = false;
        console.log(operatorText);
        userInput = firstNumber;
        firstNumber = 0;
        document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput;

    }
    else if (firstNumber && !userInput && !operatorText){
        //just to be cheeky see if we can backspace the answers
        //problem here is it is working with firstNumber NOT userInput
            //IDK WTF is going on here. i want to backspace the sums
            //string was still converted to a number...
        console.log("works");
        //firstNumber = firstNumber.toString().slice(0, -1);
        userInput = firstNumber.toString().slice(0, -1);
        document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput;
        firstNumber = 0;
            if (!userInput) {
                userInput = 0;
                console.log("it works");
                document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput;
                }
    }
    else {
    //if showing a symbol, allow user to edit first number again
    //uncheck div/add/mult/sub BOOL
    //if display is empty, show a zero
    userInput = userInput.slice(0, -1);
    if (!userInput) {
        userInput = 0;
        console.log("it works");
        document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("display").textContent = userInput;
        }
    }
});

//Clear Button
btnClear.addEventListener("click", function(){
    firstNumber = 0;
    secondNumber = 0;
    userInput = 0;
    plusSelected = false;
    subSelected = false;
    multSelected = false;
    divSelected = false;
    firstNumberStored = false;
    operatorText = '';
    document.getElementById("display").textContent = "0";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking about how to attach both events to a function, you'll want to extrapolate the required functionality into its own function and call that function on both button presses and key presses, and use the values passed to dictate how to proceed. Hopefully this sets you in the right direction:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" value="1" id="btn1"> 1 </button>
    <button type="button" value="2" id="btn2"> 2 </button>
    <button type="button" value="3" id="btn3"> 3 </button>
    <button type="button" value="4" id="btn4"> 4 </button>
    <button type="button" value="5" id="btn5"> 5 </button>
    <button type="button" value="6" id="btn6"> 6 </button>
    <button type="button" value="7" id="btn7"> 7 </button>
    <button type="button" value="8" id="btn8"> 8 </button>
    <button type="button" value="9" id="btn9"> 9 </button>
    <button type="button" value="0" id="btn0"> 0 </button>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// Selecting the buttons container div for simplicity
const buttons = document.querySelector(".buttons")

// main functionality goes here
const buttonAction = (input) => {
  console.log(input)
}

// FYI these are both listening to synthetic events and capturing some info from the event:
// listen for button presses, sends the parsed integer value from the button to the buttonAction function. I've added a value field to the html to accomplish this
buttons.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const buttonNumber = parseInt(e.target.value)
  buttonAction(buttonNumber)
})

// listen for key presses, if the key successfully parses to an integer, sends it to the buttonAction function, else ignore
document.onkeypress = (e) => {
  const keyNumber = parseInt(e.key)
  if (parseInt(e.key)) {
    buttonAction(keyNumber)
  }
}
```